# Dapper stored procedure call to correct database

Tags: c#, asp.net, dapper

I have the following single database structure:

```
Server
  |
  Database
    + Tables
    + Programmability(stored procedures)
```

In which I am using the following method to make a stored procedure call using Dapper:

```
public List<Events> GetEvents()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SQLSettings.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        return connection.Query<Events>("GetEvents", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
    }

}
```

But now I'm changing the back end to a multiple database structure, like:

```
Server
  |
  Database1
    + Tables
    + Programmability(stored procedures)
  |
  Database2
    + Tables
    + Programmability(stored procedures)
```

My question is, how do I need to modify my method to ensure so that it is hitting the correct database where the stored procedure resides?

Comment: Which DB it uses is based on the connection string.

Comment: I figured it was something simple. Thanks to all for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ensuring it with proper connection string.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Connection string of the first db"))
{
    return connection.Query<Events>("GetEvents", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
}

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Connection string of the second db"))
{
    return connection.Query<Events>("GetEvents", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know in which DB (1 or 2) to find the SP, use either of these:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SQLSettings.GetConnectionString1()))
{ ... }
```

or

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SQLSettings.GetConnectionString2()))
{ ... }
```